# How to update B2B Management Policy via MS Graph / Graph Explorer?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I need to figure out how to update my B2B Management policy via ms graph.
This is how I'm currently doing it via powershell and the azure ad preview module:

```
Connect-AzureAD
$currentpolicy = Get-AzureADPolicy -All $true | ?{$_.Type -eq 'B2BManagementPolicy'} | select -First 1
$currentpolicy

$newPolicyValue = @("{`"B2BManagementPolicy`":{`"InvitationsAllowedAndBlockedDomainsPolicy`":{`"AllowedDomains`": [`"x.com`",`"y.org`",`"asdf.org`",`"fff.com`"],`"BlockedDomains`": []}}}")
#update existing policy
Set-AzureADPolicy -Definition $newPolicyValue -Id $currentpolicy.Id
```

This works - i'm able to update the list of domains that are allowed in this tenant.

Ultimately, I need to do this is in c# application, but to start I'm trying to see if Graph Explorer exposes any API that will do this.

The MS doc I've been using is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/allow-deny-list

They don't provide any .NET core samples .. but I thought I'd ask here just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any documentation on the graph API either. However, they present the data over this API:

https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/B2B/b2bPolicy

Following Headers are needed:

```
Authorization: Bearer <<token>>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
x-ms-client-request-id:
```

The second value is empty by intent - it works without any value being passed. Any value can be used instead however.

Finally, your body should be:

```
{
    "targetedDomains": [
        "my-domain-test.com"
     ],
    "isAllowlist": true,
    "hasListEntries": true,
    "adminConsentedForUsersIntoTenantIds": [],
    "noAADConsentForUsersFromTenantsIds": [],
    "otpEnabled": false
}
```